# Regular Expression to validate multiple condition

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I require to validate a string using javascript with multiple conditions. I am not sure how to do this using regular expressions.

I need to check if the string does not contain any of the following conditions

**Condition 1**: String of any length beginning with 18XX or 1-8XX or 8XX, where X is any number from 0 to 9 (both 0 and 9 being inclusive). ***Ex: 1800abc, 812abc-def, 1-805-999-9999***

**Condition 2**: The string beginning with NXX or 1NXX or 1-NXX followed by exactly seven numbers not including hyphens, where N is any number from 2 to 9 (both 2 and 9 being inclusive) and X is any number from 0 to 9 (both 0 and 9 being inclusive). ***Ex: 12-999-9999, 19009998888, 1-212---1-2-3-4-5-6-7--***

**Condition 3**: The string beginning with XXXXX, where X is any number from 0 to 9 (both 0 and 9 being inclusive). ***Ex: 20176, 90210-Melrose***

Comment: to match all with regex could be fail try some string function along with regex.

Comment: I stumbled here looking for advanced regex conditionals.  But I'm curious on the logic.  If any of these conditions exist, fail?  Or, if all exist, fail?  Or if any exist, collect all or a portion?  Or only if all exist, collect all or a portion of the match?  I assume this is a short input with limited characters (under 1k).  And you want to validate the input by validating the beginning of the string, and if any of the conditions match, flag success and gather the match value.  In which case, just for fun, I made this:
^(\d{5}(?=\D)|1?-*(8\d{2}|[2-9]\d{0,2}(-*\d){7}-*)).*$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>you cannot have a single regex match all this,</strike> *Er may be you can!! see below*

try using these three for each condition, check for all three and pass only those that **do not** match any.

condition 1: `^1?-?8\d{2}.*$`

condition 2: **remove all hypens first** then match for `^1?[2-9]\d{7}$`

condition 3: `^\d{5}.*$`

hope this helps

**EDIT**

You may have a single regex that can match this. 
since `-` seems to be an optional character lets remove them first, but as pointed out by *@nnnnn* in the comments, lets first check if the string actually **begins** with a `-` if it does then the string passes validation without further checks.
then you can string those three together with `|` form a single regex which you can check against

`^1?8\d{2}.*|1?[2-9]\d{7}|\d{5}.*`

i removed `-?` from the first part since we've already removed all hypens.

Comment: _"you cannot have a single regex match all this"_ - Why not? Can't you do it with `|`? For condition 2 you can't remove all hyphens first or you will get false matches on strings that originally had leading hyphens...

Comment: @nnnnnn of course you can, how silly of me :). i have updated. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for alternation:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

To match digits, you can use the digits class `\d` or just plain `[0-9]`.

For example for condition 1, you can attempt to match it with:

```
 /^18\d\d|1-8\d\d|8\d\d$/.test("1800")  == true
 /^18\d\d|1-8\d\d|8\d\d$/.test("1-800") == true
 /^18\d\d|1-8\d\d|8\d\d$/.test("812")   == true
```

Of course, you can get smart with [optional items](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html), and [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) to come up with something like:

```
 /^(1-?)?8\d\d$/.test("1-800") == true
```

You can use a tool like [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) to experiment with regular expressions. I usually just play with it in the Chrome Developer Tools console.

Try to figure out the rest on your own. :)